# How to have 1 column in a flex box fill remaining space

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following html:

```
<div id="inner-container">
   <div id="titles">
       <div id="main-title">Main title here</div>
       <div id="page-title">Page title here</div>
   </div>
   <nav id="progress-container>
       <div id="page-counter">Page count here</div>
       <a id="link-to-page-1"></a>
       <a id="link-to-page-2"></a>
       <a id="link-to-page-3"></a>
       <a id="link-to-page-4"></a>
       <a id="link-to-page-5"></a>
       <a id="link-to-page-6"></a>
   </nav>
</div>
```

and this css:

```
#inner-container {
    display: flex;
}
#titles > div {
    width: 100%;
}
#progress-container #page-counter {
    float: left;
}
#progress-container a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 12px
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    #progress-container #page-counter {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I would like to add the necessary css flex rules so that #titles occupies the full **remaining width**, left over by #progress-container.
I have tried:

```
#titles {
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

And I've tried various rules for #page-progress, including 'flex-basis: auto' and 'flex-basis: content', but nothing has worked.

Note that I cannot set a fixed width to #progress-container as the number of 'pages' is dynamic and will vary. Also the #page-counter  disappears below 900px.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd like to hear them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding flex: 1; in #titles.
learn about flex properties over [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
#titles {
 flex: 1; 
}
```

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/shahilparichay/pen/XWZxzmB)

Comment: I have read that page previously and it doesn't provide an explanation. I've also tried using the various 'flex-basis: content' options, but that didn't work. What I've provided above is a simplified version. When I add 'flex: 1' in the live version, it forces the #titles column to a narrow width. Just looking into why. Works in the codepen though. Have you been able to find a clearer explanation of what the values of 'flex-shrink' mean? That page says it 'defines the ability for a flex item to shrink, if necessary' - which means what, exactly?

Comment: If  you want to learn about flex-shrig, flex-grow, flex-basis properties, check out this link https://css-tricks.com/understanding-flex-grow-flex-shrink-and-flex-basis/ I am also going to create a code pen just give me some time.  And if it is not working in lve link can you share some code pen link or js fiddle where I can check the code.

Comment: flex: 1, will force the div to take the remaining space, and flex-shrink means minimum width a div can shrink to allow another div to take space.

Comment: I added 'flex-shrink: 0' to the #progress-container and, in the live version, removed an additional layer of <div>s and that has worked. Since you got it working with the details I provided, your answer is correct.